# About how to use many to one in TypeORM

Tags: orm, nestjs

For the table which has Foreign key, I want to assign ManyToOne's decorator.
I know `@ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)` is just table relation,
What its argument　`() => User, user => user.photos`　means?

And please tell me  `user: User`'s property and value mean.

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./User";
@Entity()
export class Photo {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    
    @Column()
    url: string;
    
    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)
    user: User;
    
}
```

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
import {Photo} from "./Photo";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Photo, photo => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

it just sets the inverse relationship so if you want you could query the other way back. For example:

```
  await this.photoRepository.find({
    loadEagerRelations: true,
    relations: ['user'],
  })
```

and you would have something like :

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "url": "https://twetew",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    ...
    ...
  }
 }
]
```

TypeORM needs this to understand the relation and create the correct reference. In your photos database table it will create a user_id column. User won't have a photo_id.

So:

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.photos)
user: User;
```

creates a user_id column on photos database table and lets you query the other way back.